# How to add an Attribute to a XML tag in VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am trying to generate a XML file from VBA, knowing a little of VBA and less of XML.
This is my initial code

```
    Dim oDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xMetrics As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim XDoc As Object, root As Object, elem As Object
    Dim rel As Object
    
'    oDoc.Load "C:\Users\Claudio\Downloads\IT04384550879_00598.xml"

    Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set root = XDoc.createElement("StandardBusinessDocument")
    XDoc.appendChild root

'Add child to root
    Set elem = XDoc.createElement("StandardBusinessDocumentHeader")
    root.appendChild elem
```

that correctly generates the following

```
<StandardBusinessDocument>
    <StandardBusinessDocumentHeader/>
</StandardBusinessDocument>
```

But when I try to add an attribute to the root

```
    Set rel = XDoc.createAttribute("xmlns")
    rel.NodeValue = "http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader"
    root.setAttributeNode rel
```

it adds the attribute to all tags, giving

```
<StandardBusinessDocument xmlns="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader">
    <StandardBusinessDocumentHeader xmlns=""/>
</StandardBusinessDocument>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works (append to xmlDoc at the end and add attribute before to append child):

```
Sub GenerateXML()
    ' Create a DOMDocument object
    Dim xmlDoc As Object
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    ' Create the root element
    Dim root As Object
    Set root = xmlDoc.createElement("StandardBusinessDocument")

    ' Set the xmlns attribute for the root element
    root.setAttribute "xmlns", "http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader"

    ' Create the StandardBusinessDocumentHeader element
    Dim elem As Object
    Set elem = xmlDoc.createElement("StandardBusinessDocumentHeader")

    ' Append the StandardBusinessDocumentHeader element to the root element
    root.appendChild elem

    ' Append the root element to the document
    xmlDoc.appendChild root

    ' Display the content of the XML document
    Debug.Print xmlDoc.XML
End Sub
```